# XML Tools for Notepad++: libXML and/or libXSLT missing

Tags: windows-10, installation, notepad++, plugins, xml

I installed XML Tools 2.4.11 using Plugin Manager, however the only thing showing up in menu is **How to install** item and clicking on it I get a message:

> Unable to load libXML and/or libXSLT.
>
> Please install external DLLs into NPP root directory (same directory
>   than Notepad++.exe) or in "%appdata%\Notepad++" folder and restart
>   NPP.
>
> These libraries are available in the subfolder "ext_libs" of xmltools
>   zip archive.

If I look into my Notepad++ folder, I can clearly see there's both *libxml2-2.dll* and *libxslt-1.dll*. I tried replacing them with an older version bundled with [XML Tools from 2016](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XML%20Tools/Xml%20Tools%202.4.9%20Unicode/), but I'm getting the same error.

I have 32-bit version of Notepad++ on 64-bit Windows. Here's my debug info:

```
Notepad++ v7.5.9   (32-bit)
Build time : Oct 14 2018 - 15:02:52
Path : C:\Program Files(x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
Admin mode : OFF
Local Conf mode : OFF
OS : Windows 10 (64-bit)
Plugins : NppExport.dll DSpellCheck.dll mimeTools.dll NppConverter.dll NppTextFX.dll NppXmlTreeviewPlugin.dll PluginManager.dll Tidy2.dll XMLTools.dll
```

Not sure what to do here to make this work.

Comment: The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274154/notepad-xmltools-not-installing) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/690783/make-xml-tools-plugin-work-with-notepad) might fix the problem (presumably they have helped some people as they are upvoted, but I tried all this and it still didn't work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried some of the answers that Mr. Hooper linked, and also did not have success. After a whole lot of see-if-this-fix-works, I ended up completely uninstalling without saving any settings, grabbed the absolute latest installer (7.6.2 - 32bit), and installed it. Then, using the built-in Plugins Admin, I installed XML Tools, and it worked!

It should be noted that Notepad++ 7.5.8 (32 bit) with XML Tools 2.4.9 (manually installed) DID work as well. I still don't have an answer as to what's causing the problem, which is the frustrating part, but I THINK it might have something to do with an update process vs. uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Well that fixed it. I guess there was something off with my installation. I don't know why I had 32-bit version to begin with. I also didn't have Plugins Admin, I had to manually install Plugin Manager. Installed Notepad++ with default settings and everything magically works.

Answer (score 5):

I had an issue with XML Tools failing to install via the Plugins Admin even when reinstalling the latest version of NPP (currently 7.7.1).

It turned out that a corporate firewall was blocking the Plugins Admin from accessing the repository. Unfortunately, there is no notification in the UI for this which is causing a very frustrating experience of nothing happening.

It took me a while and some Googling to figure out how to manually install the latest version of XML Tools (2.4.11) with Notepad++ higher than v7.6:

- please download xmltools manually from here: https://github.com/morbac/xmltools/releases/download/2.4.11.0/Xml.Tools.2.4.11.0.x86.Unicode.zip
- extract Xml.Tools.2.4.11.0.x86.Unicode.zip anywhere to a temporary
  location
- create a folder XMLTools inside of **Detination Folder***
- copy the files XMLTools.dll and change.log as well as the whole    folder libs from the extracted
  Xml.Tools.2.4.11.0.x86.Unicode folder    to: {**Detination Folder***}\XMLTools
- restart notepad++ (only necessary if it was opened while copying the    xmltools plugin to it’s folder destination)

**Destination Folder:**

- %ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\plugins\ (32 bit OS)
- %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Notepad++\plugins\ (64 bit OS, 32 bit Npp)
- %ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\plugins\ (64 bit OS, 64 bit Npp)

Source: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/16983/xml-tools/11

Answer (score 3):

## Try with new default plugin manager

I still had the OLD plugin manager inside NPPx86.

A while back there was a bit of drama in the NPP project and the old plugin manager [got kicked out of NPP in version 7.5 on 2017-08-16.](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-7.5-released.html) (Archived [here](https://archive.fo/uUpUL).)

So, back then, if you wanted to have any plugin manager at all then [you had to manually insert the old plugin manager into NPP yourself.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46301700/how-to-view-plugin-manager-in-notepad) And that's what I did.

But now NPP seems to bring its own NEW plugin manager.

So I uninstalled NPP, deleted `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Notepad++` and deleted `%appdata%\Notepad++`. And then did a reinstall using "Notepad++ Installer 32-bit x86" (npp.7.6.6.Installer.exe).

Then via `Plugins | Plugins Admin...`
[image: Plugins | Plugins Admin]

I was successfully able to install `XML Tools`.
[image: Plugins Admin window with XML Tools]

So fresh install did the trick for me. (But if you're hesitant you might first try to throw out the old plugin manager manually somehow before you reinstall.)

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me too (7.6.6 32-bit).  What were you going to write after "Here's a little background for the"?  Left everyone hanging!

Comment: @jay: Oh right. Sorry. I first wanted to add the link to the drama there. But then i just made it an inline link instead. :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is a compatibility issue with the XML Tools Plugin and 7.6+ Notepad++ versions.

Basically, you have two options:

- If you are still on **NPP 7.5** you can **manually install the XML tools (2.4.9.x Unicode)** from SF [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/postdownload) and avoid auto-updates of the plugins until you are ready to move
- or you **start fresh now with NPP 7.6+** and use the new built-in Plugin Admin as suggested by the other answers using XML Tools 2.4.11+ (it seems there is no 2.4.10).

You can find some interesting pointers related to this case in this [NPP community thread](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/16983/xml-tools/8).

Comment: See my answer about a third option (installing manually with NPP 7.6+)

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in install.txt file in XML Tool plugin. You have to copy XMLTools.dll not into the plugins directory, but into plugins\XMLTools subdirectory.